# react-materialize Tabs: switching content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, redux, materialize

I have a couple of Modals and each of them contains Tabs. When I trigger the first one, everything works correctly (tabs and their content change) but when I trigger others, first tab is displaying but i can't switch to another tab or just content doesn't change. I try to console.log event object and it shows correct tab number after click.

In parent component I map through list of devices and create Modals.

```
<Modal
     id={device}
     header={device}
     fixedFooter
     trigger={
       <div className="deviceSettingDiv">
          <Icon className="deviceSettingButton">settings</Icon>
       </div>
     }>
     <DeviceConfiguration deviceId={device}/>
</Modal>
```

Child's component render function contains only Tabs

```
return(
    <Tabs>
       <Tab title="Step 1">
          <h2> Device </h2>
       </Tab>
       <Tab title="Step 2">
          <h2>Communication</h2>
       </Tab>
       <Tab title="Step 3">
          <h2>Paramlist</h2>
       </Tab>
    </Tabs>
    )
```

I got rid of majority of Tabs content for better view.
Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong ?